# Ordering word using Regax search in mongo db Or java program (order by searching word position)

Tags: java, mongodb

In our project we use java with Mongodb

In our requirement we should display searching word is first remaining next

**eg**:

**Sample Query** db.getCollection('user').find( { "$and" : [{ "name" : { "$regex" : "kuma"}}]})

**Expected Result**

1. kumar
2. kumarasan
3. rajkumar
4. arunkumar
5. rajaskumar
6. etc...

How to get the result in above order using java program

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your exact problem?

Comment: I need a result as Expected Result order, first display the word starting position is first (1st)  then next position(2nd) then next position(3rd) and so on. eg: 1. kumar, 2.akumar, 3.abkumar

Comment: So not possible currently to do before you return results from the server. [SERVER-11947](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) discusses addition of a new aggregation operator where part of the spec would be to return "group matches" in which you "could" in theory use the additional match groups to calculate a "ranking" and then sort on that calculated field. Notably this has been recently marked as "desired" for the MongoDB 4.1 release. This should indicate work is in progress to resolve.